# js 13 discord buttons clicked one

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am writing tickets to the system. Reports come to a special channel. There is an "accept" button, it works, but when more than one report arrives, if you click on the "accept" button, then all reports will be accepted

[2 reports IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bG5a.png)

[i clicked one IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fsSN.png)

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
                    if(interaction.isButton()) {
                        if (interaction.customId.includes(`acceptB`)) {
                             myacceptB.edit({embeds:[editEmbRep]})
                            interaction
                            let channelx =   interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(myreportChannel)
                            if(channelx){

                                  channelx.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.user.id,{ VIEW_CHANNEL: true,SEND_MESSAGES: true,ATTACH_FILES: true,READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY:true })}
```

Might need to use a unique idButton each time, but I don't know how to check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should only edit the message that the button clicked is attached to. There is no need for unique ID’s for each button when you edit the message the interaction is attached to.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if(interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === `acceptB`) {
   
            const editEmbRep = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('New Embed')
   
            interaction.message.edit({
                content: 'updated text', // to change the text
                embeds: [editEmbRep], // to change the embed
                components: [] // if you want to remove the button
            })
   
// Not sure what you are trying to do with this part so I didn’t do anything with it. 

            let channelx = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(myreportChannel)
            if (channelx) {
                channelx.permissionOverwrites.edit(
                    interaction.user.id,
                    {
                        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
                        SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                        ATTACH_FILES: true,
                        READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY:true
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes thanks, it helped me. I create a private channel in this command, but when I click on the "accept" button, the person who clicks on it is added to all the channels that were sent to the report, this is described in the code below the post edit. How can I make it subscribe to a specific channel? I am passing the channel id in the "myreportChannel" variable.

Comment: So the channel never changes but you need to add them to the at channel when you click accept? Just making sure I understand

Comment: when the report command is written, a channel is created whose id is in the "myreportChannel" variable, when someone clicks the "accept" button, I want to add rights to the channel to him. When 2 reports are received at once, the person who pressed the "accept" button will register in all other channels. I need it to fit in one

Comment: Please formulate this as a new question and provide code for channel creation, any messages sent when it is created and the above code for when it is accept

Comment: ye, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962838/discord-js-13-button-edit-permission-channel)